# How to determine which columns to use as foreign keys?

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-key-relationship

I need a bit of refresher regarding SQL Database Design, particularly how and what columns to use for a Foreign Key.

Below are 2 designs I came up with, can please tell which makes more sense? For me, I believe Design 2 seems better..

EDIT:

A Project can contain only 1 Team. A Team can have one or more Team Members. Likewise, a Team Member can be part of one or more Teams. I am using Microsoft Visio, UML Crow Foot Notation to create these images.

The main reason I separated Project from ProjectTeamOrg is to segregate the data, as realistically, I am going to have many elements for a Project and am separating these into their own DB Tables.

**Design 1**
[image: Design 1]

**Design 2**
[image: Design 2]

Comment: Is that `Project -> ProjectTeamOrg` a *one-to-one* relationship?

Comment: shouldn't the tables Project and ProjectTeamOrg be merged?

Comment: which tool are you using to generate these images? =)

Comment: Can a team member be on more than one project? The diagram shows it that way, I just want to be sure. The diagram also shows each project can have only one team member -- I'm fairly sure that is wrong.

Comment: Sorry I only replied today, was gone for the weekend :( A Project can contain only 1 Team. A Team can have one or more Team Members. Likewise, a Team Member can be part of one or more Teams. I am using Microsoft Visio, UML Crow Foot Notation to create these images.

Comment: Design 1 seems better

Answer (score 0):

Tell me about the relation ship between these tables..either one to one (or) one to many.Becoz this relationship helps us to determine which column in the table should have Foreign key.

**Go with Design 1**

According to the thing which i understood;

```
    Tablename         Columnname    Key 
    Project            Projectid   Primary   
    Projectteamorg     Projectid   Foreign(Reference Project(Projectid))   
    Projectteammember  teamid      Primary  
    Projectteamorg     teamid      Foreign(Reference Projectteammember(teamid))
```

Comment: That would be a perfect **comment**

Comment: the relationship is already specified by the image, || means one to one and >| means one to many

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the database is not clear. You did not explain the flow of data. I am unable to see the Team table. Is it there? or the ProjectTeamOrg is team table.

Please explain the flow of data. Then one can be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry I only replied today, was gone for the weekend :( A Project can contain only 1 Team. A Team can have one or more Team Members. Likewise, a Team Member can be part of one or more Teams. I am using Microsoft Visio, UML Crow Foot Notation to create these images.